# How to bind observable collection to canvas with converter

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, data-binding

I have a collection of functions that I want to plot them on canvas. So I think the correct data type to plot these functions is `Polyline`.

So I need a converter to convert these functions into collection of polylines and finally show them in canvas.

Here is XAML code.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WaveCollection, 
                RelativeSource ={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                Converter={StaticResource PlotterConverter}}" Margin="10,10,0,239" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="330">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="GhostWhite" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And here is part of the converter which converts waveforms into polylines. The binding mode is one way.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var collection = value as IEnumerable<Waveform>;
    return new ObservableCollection<Polyline>(GetPlots(collection));
}
```

However when I put break point, I notice that it only fires once when the program starts. The collection is empty yet so nothing especial happens, but after that, when I add items to collection nothing happens. No event fires. Why?

To make sure I also added this code to converter to see if it really fires or not but nothing happened.

```
var collection = value as ObservableCollection<Waveform>;
collection.Clear(); // this is supposed to clear collection. if binding works correct!
//...
```

Note that I also binded this collection into `listview` to show information of waves which works fine when the collection updates.

Edit:

I guess the problem is this part `return new ObservableCollection<Polyline>...` which changes the collection in first run and will mess up binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of converting the whole `ObservableCollection` at once, use a converter that takes one item at a time.

In this case, this means that you specify the type of control each item shall be displayed as by defining the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate` in XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding WaveCollection, 
                RelativeSource ={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Margin="10,10,0,239" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="330">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="GhostWhite" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Polyline Points="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource PlotterConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The `PlotterConverter` will now be passed each item on its own, so all it needs to do is convert a `Waveform` object to an object of type `PointCollection` (since the `Polyline`'s `Points` property is of type `PointCollection`):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var item = value as Waveform;
    return new PointCollection(GetPlot(item));
}
```

Of course, the `GetPlot` method needs to be adapted as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.